# How to enter a linear model with many factors

Tags: r, lm, factors

It may be a basic question, but I could not seem to find a solution anywhere. If we have a data frame with 100 factors (call them `a1` to `a100`), how could a linear model be entered in R? I understand you could write

```
lm(y~ a1*...*a100)
```

but if the names are long, it would take  a long time to write them all out. Is there a faster way? For example, by referencing columns or something similar? Somewhat related, if I get a data table with a column name that involves parentheses (e.g. `y-max()`), how could I enter that? It reads as a function in R, but it is not.

I apologize if this has already been asked, but I could not seem to find an answer.

Thank you all in advance

---Edit---

Thank you for the answers. However, if I did want higher-order interaction terms, how would I accomplish that? Would I need to write a script or is there a smarter way?

Comment: just checking: you don't *really* want all higher-order interactions among 100 predictors, do you [that's what the formula syntax you wrote above technically means]?  That would correspond to a model with `2^100` terms ... If you want an *additive* model of all those terms (less crazy), see the linked question above.

Comment: for `y-max()`, you should use backticks `\`y-max()\``

Answer (score 3):

if you want to include all others `y~.` is enough, but if you want some selected vars, lets say, var 2 to 50, 52-100. you can do something like this?

```
vars<-names(df)[c(2:50,52:101)] #or whatever..
covs<-paste(vars, collapse="+")
model<-paste("y~",covs)
df.lm<-lm(as.formula(model), data=df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Many of these things should be possible to figure out by reading the [Introduction to R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) that comes with R when you download it.

Generally, a factor with many levels is stored as a single variable:

```
treat <- c("control", "placebo", "placebo", "control", "drugA", "control", 
           "drugB", ...)
```

If so, you can just use `lm(y~treat)`, and R will handle this for you.  On the other hand, if you have a data frame with `y` and `a1` through `a100` *only*, then you can use `lm(y~., my.data)`, and R will take care of that for you also.